# HttpMessageConverter not found in Spring restTemplate

Tags: spring, rest

I have got error when I retrieve JSON using String restTempate. Error says

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type  [class au.org.jeenee.mdm.models.PhoneResponse] and content type [application/json]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:447)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:295)
    at au.org.jeenee.mdm.services.EccClientServiceImpl.findPhoneByImei(EccClientServiceImpl.java:51)
    at au.org.jeenee.mdm.controllers.DeviceController.showEditForm(DeviceController.java:308)
```

I found out the message means there is no JSON converter registered but I have Jackson message converter in my `xml`.

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
           <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
       </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
   <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And here is my code to use RestTemplate.

```
public class MyRestClientService {
@Override
    public List<DeviceHolder> findDeviceHoldersByUserId(String userId) {
        String uri = "/web/getpersonlist?userId=" + userId;
        try {
            DeviceHolderResponse response = restClient.getRestTemplate().postForObject(restClient.createUrl(uri), "", DeviceHolderResponse.class);


            if (response!=null && response.isOk() && response.getResult()!=null){

                DeviceHolder[] deviceHolders = response.getResult();
                return Arrays.asList(deviceHolders);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public Phone findPhoneByImei(String imei) {
        log.info("findPhoneByImei:" + imei);

        Phone phone = null;
        String uri = "/ecc/getphoneplan?imei=" + imei;
        try {
            PhoneResponse response = restClient.getRestTemplate().postForObject(restClient.createUrl(uri), "", PhoneResponse.class);
            if (response.getResult()!=null)
                phone = response.getResult();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return phone;
    }
}

PhoneResponse.java
public class Phone implement Serializable {
   private boolean ok;
   private String message;
   private Phone result;

  //getters and setters
}


Phone.java
public class Phone implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty(value="phoneid")
    private long phoneId;

    private Plan plan;
    private String sim;
    private String imei;

    @JsonProperty(value="phonetype")
    private String phoneType;

    @JsonProperty(value="phonenumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String label;
    @JsonProperty(value="connecteddate")
    private String connectedDate;

//getters and setters
}

Plan.java
public class Plan implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty(value="planid")
    private long planId;

    @JsonProperty(value="planname")
    private String planName;

    private double billingIncrement;

    private double owiStdUnitCost;

    private double owiFlagFall;

    private double stdCap;

    private double dataCap;

    private double smsCap;

    private double owiDataUnitCost;

    private double owiSms;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the response packet is like following:

```
{
   "ok": true,
   "message": "",
   "result":
   {
       "phoneid": 600003,
       "phonenumber": 478439503,
       "phonetype": "Samsung Galaxy S2",
       "imei": "1111111111",
       "sim": "1111111111",
       "label": "Person name",
       "connecteddate": "2012-09-19 00:00:00.0",
       "plan":
       {
           "planid": 34,
           "planname": "$59 Plan",
           "billingIncrement": 30,
           "owiStdUnitCost": 81.8181818181818,
           "owiFlagFall": 0,
           "stdCap": 636.3636,
           "dataCap": 227.2665,
           "smsCap": 1363.638,
           "owiDataUnitCost": 0.022194,
           "owiSms": 22.7272727272727
       }
   }
}
```

Strangely, there is no error when I call `findDeviceHoldersByUserId` method but error for `findPhoneByImei` method. And this has been working up to just before.

I tried again and again but I still have the error. Please help to fix the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you've declared the bean with name or id of jacksonMessageConverter - could you clarify where/how this bean is defined - I apologize if I've missed the declaration as well.

Comment: @Dave I already put it but because of the format issue, it did not display property in the question. I fixed it.

Comment: thanks for editing that back in - next question - which Jackson are you using - 1 or 2 - I'm under the impression 1.  Try this - can you run this code in a debugger? put a break point in HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData() and verify that it does in fact have the converter registered as well as the 'canRead' method of the converter under inspection can interpret the response.

Comment: @Dave Thanks again. My version is 1.9.12.
From my research, the error comes from 
HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T>.extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) method. I think there can be two reason to cause the problem. One is I do not have jacksonMessageConverter registered or the other is it cannot convert response. In my case, it looks the second one is the problem, so I will add domain class as well.

Comment: I found out what was problem, but it does not make sense very much to me. There are two things to be fixed in my source.
1. Phonenumber field in Phone class in String type but return value is Integer.
2. owiFlagFall in the Plan class is double type but the return is Integer 0, not 0.0. 

I modified number 1 and 2 and now it works fine, however still I do not understand about number 2.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to track that down - so for the first one, the JSON value of phone number that is passed is unquoted - it will attempt to process that as a numeric value. For the second, it will attempt to process that as an integer (or potentially long) value because the value in the JSON is not a decimal value (e.g. 0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of reasons, I found, that can cause this issue are -

1. Data type of the setters/getters are different from that of the actual properties (also mentioned in comment of sunghun)
2. If there are overloaded methods that may look like setter/getter of a field - same name as setField or getField where field is a property of the class.

I had a field `private boolean success` and 2 setter methods -

```
public void setSuccess(List<Object> dataList);
public void setSuccess(boolean success);
```

On debugging, I found that class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory` was throwing an exception. This exception was suppressed within Jackson's lib and the exception thrown by the RestTemplate was the same as the subject.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "failure": com.test.dto.JsonResponse#setFailure(1 params) vs com.test.dto.JsonResponse#setFailure(1 params)
```

I changed the method to `public void setSuccessData(List<Object> dataList);` and it worked fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: To make debugging easier: The place where the exception is suppressed is in org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationConfig, JavaType). The relevant code block looks like this: `try { deser = _createAndCacheValueDeserializer(config, type, null); } catch (Exception e) { return false; }`. Set a breakpoint there to investigate the Exception further.

Comment: In our case, the problem was the Java Generic mechanism. We had a class `SuperClass<T>` with a getter `T getValue()` and a setter `setValue(T)`. A `SubClass extends SuperClass<Type>` was overriding the setter as `setValue(Type)`. Because of the way that Generics work, the getter was returning `Object` and not `Type`, so the PropertyDescriptor was reporting a mismatch between getter and setter. We simply solved it by overriding the getter: `Type getValue() { return super.getValue(); }`